# How can I pass a column name as a parameter to SQL in R sqldf?

Tags: r, sqldf

How can I pass a column name as a parameter to SQL in R sqldf?

Neither

```
q <- "Q10"

A = fn$sqldf('SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE $q < 100')
```

or

```
q <- "Q10"

A = fn$sqldf('SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE '$q' < 100')
```

works.

Comment: Define "works".  The first one looks ok if Q10 is a numeric column in Customer.  Suggest you make your example reproducible by providing `dput(head(Customer))`.

Comment: It's a string column. The column's name is "Q10".
I get an error:


Error in source("~/Paul/R/DTA/Success rate123_2.R", echo = TRUE) : 
  ~/Paul/R/DTA/Success rate123_2.R:3:63: unexpected string constant

2: q <- "Q10"

3: pred01 =fn$sqldf('SELECT * FROM CustomerQ_totals123T WHERE '$q' < $fract*Q9 AND Total > -1 ORDER BY Total DESC'
                                                                 ^

Comment: NEITHER of the above work.

Comment: Just so you know, it's a little rude to SHOUT AT THE PEOPLE TRYING TO HELP YOU. Particularly, when that person is the author of the package you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I just use capitals for emphasis in all my communications, email or otherwise! I thought it seemed that GG needed the NEITHER emphasised. I'm not a regular on forums in the last 10 years so I'm 10 years out of date in net etiquette.

Comment: > head(CustomerQ_totals123T)  
    
  Customer_code      Industry_sector      Q1      Q2   Q3      Q4     Q5      Q6      Q7       Q8       Q9     Q10     Q11      Q12    Total  
1       1000019          Distributor    0.00    0.00    0    0.00    0.0    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00   420.0     0.0     0.00   420.00  
2       1000024     Private Hospital    0.00    0.00    0    0.00    0.0    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.0     0.0     0.00     0.00

Comment: The Q10 column is numeric.
It's title is string obviously.

Comment: OK, I found a trivial bug. Thanks and apologies all!

Comment: OK, I found a trivial error. Sorry folks.
Yes, the FIRST listing does work.

Answer (score 4):

`sprintf()` will work charmingly in this case. Personally, I find code using `sprintf()` to be more easy to read (and even write) than `paste()`.

```
q <- "Q10"
sql <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE %s < 100", q)

sql
[1] "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Q10 < 100"
```

In fact, you can go much further with compiling complex SQL queries. Just to illustrate:

```
q <- "Q10"
value <- "150"
sql <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE %s < %s", q, value)

sql
[1] "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Q10 < 150"
```

Comment: I do `sql <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.name=%s", 'Leo'); DF <- sqldf( sql );`. I get `Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) :  no such column: Leo`, although `Leo` column exists and the command `sqldf("SELECT * FROM a,b WHERE a.name='Leo'")` works independently. What do you think? Can you please clarify your answer? - - You need `sql <- "... '%s'"`. Also here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36881772/54964

Answer (score 2):

***Solution:***

You can use `paste` command to concatenate variable and string.

```
> library(sqldf)
> my_names <- names(sqldf("select * from iris limit 10"))
> sqldf(paste("select",my_names[1], "from iris limit 2", sep=" "))
      Sepal_Length
1          5.1
2          4.9
```

or using `fn$` to perform the string interpolation, the last line could be written:

```
> fn$sqldf("select `my_names[1]` from iris limit 2")
```

***Potential Problem:***

The names might be different when you try to use sqldf to query. 
For example, the default names for dataset `iris` is:

```
> names(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

However, the names have to be formatted in a different way when you try to use the column names to make queries:

```
> sqldf("select * from iris limit 1")
  Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

This is the [official explaination](https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#Example_1._Ordering_and_Limiting):

`Here is an example of sorting and limiting output from an SQL select statement on the iris data frame that comes with R. Note that although the iris dataset uses the name Sepal.Length the RSQLite layer converts that to Sepal_Length.`

So that is the reason in my solution I first created the `my_names` variable from `sqldf` select statement instead of `names(iris)`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the sprintf is the perfect solution, you need to change the %s by %d for integers i think.

```
q= 'Q10' ; value= 150
sql <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE %s < %d", q, value)

sql
[1] "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Q10 < 150"
```