# R sprintf in sqldf's like

Tags: r, printf, sqldf

I would like to do a looping query in R using sqldf to that select all non-NULL X.1 variable with date "11/12/2015" and at 9AM. Example :

```
StartDate              X.1
11/12/2015 09:14        A
11/12/2015 09:36        
11/12/2015 09:54        A
```

The date is in variable that generated from other query

```
nullob<-0
dayminnull<-as.numeric(sqldf("SELECT substr(Min(StartDate),1,03)as hari     from testes")) # this produce "11/12/2015"
  for (i in 1 : 12){
    dday<-mdy(dayminnull)+days(i) #go to next day
    sqlsql <- sprintf("SELECT count([X.1]) FROM testes where StartDate like '% \%s 09: %'", dday)
    x[i]<-sqldf(sqlsql)
    nullob<-nullob+x[i]
}
```

And it comes with error : Error in sprintf("SELECT count([X.1]) FROM testes WHERE StartDate like '%%s 09%'",  : 
  unrecognised format specification '%'
Please hellp. thank you in advance

Comment: Suggest you use fn$ instead of sprintf.  See example 5 on the sqldf home page: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not *super* clear in the documentation, but a `%` followed by a `%`, that is `%%`, is the way to tell `sprintf` to use a literal `%`. We can test this fairly easily:

```
sprintf("%% %s %%", "hi")
[1] "% hi %"
```

For your query string, this should work:

```
sprintf("SELECT count([X.1]) FROM testes where StartDate like '%% %s 09: %%'", dday)
```

---

From `?sprintf`:

> The string fmt contains normal characters, which are passed through to
>   the output string, and also conversion specifications which operate on
>   the arguments provided through `...`. The allowed conversion
>   specifications start with a `%` and end with one of the letters in the
>   set `aAdifeEgGosxX%`. These letters denote the following types:
>
> ... [Documentation on `aAdifeEgGosxX`]
>
> - `%`: Literal `%` (none of the extra formatting characters given below are permitted in this case).